# Really confused about where this proof came from

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ \forall s,t, x, y \in \Bbb R$, if $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, then $(sx + ty)^2 \leq s^2 + t^2$.

In the solution for this proof, they started by assuming $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ of course, and then they started the proof with something I don't get how they came up with:

"We now do some algebraic manipulation with $s, t, x, y$ and obtain
$(sx + ty)^2 + (sy - tx)^2$", then they just expanded it, and eventually reached $s^2 + t^2$. And since $(sy - tx)^2$ is positive, then $(sx + ty)^2$ is less than $s^2 + t^2$.

Answer (score 3):

We can just say $$\begin {align} (sx +ty)^2 &\le (sx+ty)^2+(sy-tx)^2\\
&=s^2x^2+t^2y^2+2stxy+s^2y^2+t^2x^2-2sxty\\
&=s^2(x^2+y^2)+t^2(x^2+y^2)\\
&=s^2+t^2 \end {align}$$
where the first line comes because we are adding a nonnegative quantity to the right side and the rest is algebra.  Adding the term they did is just what makes the proof work.  It is natural to get the cross term to be the negative of the cross term you start with.

Answer (score 1):

Well note that for all real $M$, $M^2 \ge 0$

so $0 \le (sx - ty)^2$

Add $(sx + ty)^2$ to both sides to get:

well  $(sx + ty)^2\le (sx + ty)^2 + (sy - tx)^2 $

Expand out $(sx + ty)^2$ and $(sy-tx)^2$ to get:

So $(sx + ty)^2 \le (s^2x^2 + 2stxy + t^2y^2) + (s^2y^2 - 2stxy + t^2x^2) $

Re order:

$(sx + ty)^2 \le (s^2x^2 + s^2y^2) + (t^2x^2 + t^2y^2) + (2stxy - 2stxy) =(s^2x^2 + s^2y^2) + (t^2x^2 + t^2y^2)$

Factor:

$(sx + ty)^2 \le s^2(x^2 + y^2) + t^2(x^2 + y^2)$

Replace $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ to get

$(sx + ty)^2 \le s^2*1 + t^2 *1 = s^2 + t^2$

And .... that's it.

==== Afternote ====

"If I hadn't seen the books' proof.... well I'll tell you what I would have done as an afternote..."

If I had to proof it on the spot with no prep.

I'd expand $(sx + ty)^2 = s^2x^2 + 2stxy + t^2y^2$

I'd know that I can use $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and I seem to have two halfs of it but not all all of it.  So I'll add things to get it.

$=s^2x^2 + t^2x^2 + 2stxy + s^2y^2 + t^2y^2 - t^2x^2 - s^2y^2$

$=s^2(x^2 + y^2) + t^2(x^2 + y^2) + 2stxy - t^2y^2 - s^2y^2$

$=s^2 + t^2 + 2stxy - t^2y^2 - s^2y^2$

Seeing as I had just done an expanding of a squared I'd recognize that $2stxy - t^2y^2 - s^2y^2 = -(sy -ty)^2$ so

$= s^2 + t^2 - (sy -ty)^2$.

Then I'd figure I'd gone as far as I could And i need to compare $s^2 + t^2 - (sy -ty)^2$ to $s^2 + t^2$.  And as squares are non-negative I'd get.

$(sx + ty)^2 = s^2 + t^2 - (sy-ty)^2 \le s^2 + t^2$

Comment: So the reason you started out with $$0 ≤ (sx−ty)^2$$ was because you KNEW that it would work? if you were to add the + version of it to it, you would get $s^2 + t^2$

Comment: I started with $0\le (sx -ty)^2$ because I wanted to explain thoroughly in a straight line set up for a a reader to follow.  The proof as you quoted it implied this was how the book did it and I wanted to make it line-by-line clear.  If I hadn't seen the books' proof.... well I'll tell you what I would have done as an afternote...

Answer (score 0):

The main tool that is being used is that you can write
$$(x^2 + y^2)(s^2 +t^2) = (xs+yt)^{2} + (xt -ys)^{2}.$$
This is a standard procedure that comes up in a variety of situations
(for example in number theory there is an important result on integers that can be written as a sum of two squares, this formula figures prominently); 
we can just expand it to verify it works for any $x,y,s,t$.

Then if you know that $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$, this gives you
$$s^{2}+t^{2} = (xs+yt)^{2} + (xt-ys)^{2} \geq (sx+yt)^{2}.$$